# C, GTK: window stops updating

Tags: gtk, window, cairo, updating, gdk

I'm developing an application that periodically draws images on a GTK Drawing Area inside a window.

The rendering first works well and the window content gets repainted if I drag another window over the drawing one, but after some random amount of time (some seconds), the window stops updating itself.

New images dont get displayed, and if I then drag another window over the rendering one I get this:

[image: Window content not updated anymore]

When I click one of the checkboxes below my drawing area, the window gets refreshed and the problem is gone for another few seconds.

**Any idea what could make the GTK threads stop updating the window content?**

I dont know which part of my code is of interest to answer that question, so I pasted the mostly full version [here](http://pastebin.com/Xe85yHFb).

My GTK-main() is called like this:

```
void window_main()
{
    pthread_create(&drawing_thread, NULL, img_draw, NULL);

    gtk_main();

    gdk_threads_leave();
}
```

Thanks for any hints! :)

Comment: Okay I traced the problem further down: the drawing area widget does not receive any exposure-events any more. Thats why it is not redrawn. Question is why...

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution: in the original example code I used ([here](http://cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/)) they use a `g_timeout_add()` to register their periodic drawing function.

The `g_timeout_add()`-registered function is run by `gtk_main()`, which means it is protected internally by `gdk_threads_enter()` and `gdk_threads_leave()`. That's the point I was not aware of.

Surrounded my call to `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area()` with these two functions and the bug is gone 8)